# Traductor "str" de AWS desordena <code> en Python

Tags: python

Estoy usando el traductor de AWS, es un codigo simple:
Tengo un JSON, en el que voy agregando las oraciones y otro en el que voy agregando el tiempo (con iteraciones).

```
txt = [
{
    "text": "[Music]",
    "start": 0.54,
    "duration": 5.91
},
{
    "text": "despite a wingspan of almost two and a",
    "start": 9.78,
    "duration": 5.71
},
{
    "text": "half meters this Golden Eagle hides its",
    "start": 12.46,
    "duration": 5.04
},
{
    "text": "presence by hugging the mountain slopes",
    "start": 15.49,
    "duration": 5.85
},
{
    "text": "hoping to catch its prey of God",
    "start": 17.5,
    "duration": 19.92
}
]

palabras = []
tiempos = []

for index,x in enumerate(txt):
    if x["text"] == "[Music]":
        pass
    else:
        palabras.append(f'<prosody amazon:max-duration=" {x["duration"]*1000}ms "> {x["text"]} </prosody>')
        tiempos.append(x['start'])

tiempos = [float(i) for  i  in tiempos]

for i in range(len(tiempos)-1):
    #print(i)
    if tiempos[i+1] - tiempos[i] > 6:
        #print(f'hay una pausa entre {tiempos[i+1]} y {tiempos[i]}, iteracion {i+1}')
        palabras.insert(i+1, f"<break time=' {(tiempos[i+1] - tiempos[i])*1000}ms '/>")

list = ' '.join(palabras)
```

---

```
translate = boto3.client('translate')
result = translate.translate_text(Text=list,
                                  SourceLanguageCode="en",
                                  TargetLanguageCode="de")
print(f'TranslatedText: {result["TranslatedText"]}')
print(f'SourceLanguageCode: {result["SourceLanguageCode"]}')
print(f'TargetLanguageCode: {result["TargetLanguageCode"]}')
```

Fuente: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-translate-TranslateText.py.html

El problema es que como pueden ver, no tengo como el codigo demo **Text="Hello, World"** (eso si funciona, o un str cualquiera). Cuando lo traduce cambia la comilla, le pone espacios, y aparentemente hace lo que le da la gana con el codigo, no se.

Se me ocurre que puede existir uan forma creativa para solucionar este problema, es decir, alguna forma de ocultar todo el codigo y que el traductor solo lea **{x["text"]}**, pero, que el resultado final sea con todo el codigo, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¡La edición de tu pregunta convierte en inválida mi respuesta! La borro por lo mismo.

Comment: Creo que deberías traducir los textos cuando todavía están "limpìos" y ya después crear tu marcado xml insertando en él el texto traducido, en lugar de intentar traducir el marcado xml